# How to obtain training systems within a specific time range

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a Discord Bot that can retrieve messages from Monday to Thursday
I tried asking ChatGPT first, but the sample code he gave me didn't seem to work.
as follows:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('927408798027644990');
  const now = dayjs().utcOffset(8); // UTC+8
  const startOfWeek = now.startOf('week').add(1, 'day');
  const endOfWeek = startOfWeek.add(3, 'day').endOf('day');

  const lastMondaySnowflake = SnowflakeUtil.generate(new Date(startOfWeek.valueOf()));
  const nextThursdaySnowflake = SnowflakeUtil.generate(new Date(endOfWeek.valueOf()));

  console.log('Last Monday:', startOfWeek.toISOString());
  console.log('Last Monday Snowflake:', lastMondaySnowflake);
  console.log('Next Thursday:', endOfWeek.toISOString());
  console.log('Next Thursday Snowflake:', nextThursdaySnowflake);

  try {
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ after: lastMondaySnowflake, before: nextThursdaySnowflake });
    console.log(messages.size); // why only 0?
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('撈取訊息時發生錯誤:', error);
  }
```

I looked through the Discord.js file and it seems that the fetch method does not have after or before options.

I would like to ask how I can achieve the following requirements

Only the information from this Monday to Thursday will be retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the before and after time then [`fetch`](https://discordjs.dev/docs/packages/discord.js/main/GuildMessageManager:Class#fetch) the messages with before and after options: [`FetchMessagesOptions`](https://discordjs.dev/docs/packages/discord.js/main/FetchMessagesOptions:Interface)

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('927408798027644990')
const dayInMs = 86400000 // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

let currentDate = new Date()
let daysUntilMonday = (currentDate.getDay() + 6) % 7 // difference between monday and the current day

// calculate the timestamp for the first day of the week
let firstDayOfWeek = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - daysUntilMonday * dayInMs)
// set the time to 00:00:00
firstDayOfWeek.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

// calculate the time until thursday 23:59:59
let timeUntilThursday = (4 - firstDayOfWeek.getDay() + 7) % 7 // 4 is thursday
// calculate the timestamp
let thursdayTimestamp = firstDayOfWeek.getTime() + timeUntilThursday * dayInMs + dayInMs - 1

// fetch channel messages from monday to thursday.
try {
    let messages = await channel.messages.fetch({
        after: firstDayOfWeek.getTime(),
        before: thursdayTimestamp
    })

    console.log(messages.size)
}
catch (error) {
    console.error('撈取訊息時發生錯誤:', error);
}
```